# Update Content of Div Preserving HTML Markup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to take the content of a textarea and copy it inside a div element, preserving the html markup.

When I get the content of the textarea with jQuery using .val() and log it in the console it shows the markup (ie: linebreaks). But, when I try to update the div using .html() or .text() it strips links and linebreaks.

Here is my sample code:

```js
function updateDiv() {
  var inpt = $('#textarea');
  console.log(inpt.val());
  if (inpt) {
    $('#div').text(inpt.val());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="textarea" style="height: 50px;"></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="updateDiv()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<div id="div" style="border: 1px solid gray; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GermanPearls/gcm1obhj/33/)

I've tried variations of updating html, text, value, etc but cannot get it to preserve the line breaks or markup (ie: link).

Comment: try again but using pure JS. https://www.workversatile.com/jquery-to-javascript-converter

Comment: Try using `inpt.val().replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>')` ... https://jsfiddle.net/cmsb3rLe/

Comment: I didn't know you could have links in TextAreas but certainly if you submit the form the textarea is in it won't include the link (unless written out in text) but I would suggest to you that a better solution than using a textarea would be to use the same or another contenteditable DIV.

Comment: Are you actually writing HTML to the textarea, and then try to show the result as rich text in the div?

Comment: @RoyBogado Thank you. That preserves the line breaks.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Maybe another DIV instead of the TEXTAREA would be better. I will do some testing with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want HTML say HTML.
Here I put this in the textarea `<b>b thing</b><p>in paragraph</p>` and that is the HTML that was placed in the target element.

IF you want to change text line feeds that is an entirely different matter and you need to change those to appropriate HTML characters before you update the target element.  WHAT you change them to is a matter of choice not specified in the OP if that is the real question here.

```js
function updateDiv() {
  var inpt = $('#textarea');
  console.log(inpt.val());
  if (inpt) {
    $('#div').html(inpt.val());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="textarea" style="height: 50px;"></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="updateDiv()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<div id="div" style="border: 1px solid gray; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Using .html() maintains the html markup. Then, adding the ```inpt.val().replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>')``` from @RoyBogado maintains the linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by getting the HTML part directly and providing it as the inner text element. Hope it helps.

```js
function updateDiv() {
    let inpt = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
  console.log(inpt);
  if (inpt) {
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = inpt;
  }
}
```

```html
<form >
  <textarea id="textarea" style="height: 50px;"></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="updateDiv()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<div id="div" style="border: 1px solid gray; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: I put `<b>b thing</b><p>in paragraph</p>` in your textarea and just got text in the div not HTML.

Comment: Edited the snipped. Now works with vanilla javascript as well.

Comment: Yes, now this option works as well. But line breaks will still needed to be manually converted from /n to <br/> with ```inpt.val().replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>')```

Comment: @Amy can you provide a more detailed reply? I tried to re-create your input but my snippet works correctly.

Comment: @burcu If you type in the textarea and have linebreaks in your text, the text appears all in one line in the div. To display the line breaks in the div you can replace this line: `document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = inpt;`  with this: `document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = inpt.val().replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>');`

Comment: @Amy But when I run the snippet and enter some text with line breaks to the textarea, there are no issues. I am unable to produce the same error you mention.

Comment: @burcu Strange. It's not working for me when I run your code snippet. It shows line breaks in the console output, but not the div. I don't know how to show you as I don't think I can send a screenshot in a comment.